# Where to place HttpContext.Current.RewritePath in ASP.NET 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, url-rewriting, asp.net-core

I do development in asp.net. Recently I found out that in `asp.net 5` there is no `Global.asax` file.

One of the thing to put in `Global.asax` file is URL rewriting.

With `Global.asax` file is gone. Where I can place URL rewriting code. I mean I do something like this in `ASP.NET 4.0`

```
 HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(...);
```

I do not want to use URL rewriting modules. I just want to do it using `HttpContext.Current.RewritePath` method.

My question is where I can put the above code in `ASP.NET 5`?

Comment: OWIN Middleware is the replacement for HttpModules in ASP.NET vNext.

Comment: and yeah as i said it is Startup.cs!

Comment: are there any events like Application_BeginRequest in global.asax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create and add a new middleware at the beginning of Configure method in your Startup (you want it to execute before any other middlewares). Example [here](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/269/asp-net-5-middleware-or-where-has-my-httpmodule-gone)

Implement invoke method as follows to do a url rewrite

```
public Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    // modify url
    context.Request.Path = new PathString(context.Request.Path.Value + 'whatever');
    // continue
    return _next(context);
}
```

I came across this when I was analyzing [aspnet/StaticFiles](https://github.com/aspnet/StaticFiles/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles/DefaultFilesMiddleware.cs) repo on Github.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to explicitly creating a middleware class, `IApplicationBuilder.Use` can be used too:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    //...built-in initialization...

    app.Use(requestDelegate =>
    {
        return new RequestDelegate(context =>
        {
            // modify url (from mbudnik's answer)
            context.Request.Path = new PathString(context.Request.Path.Value + 'whatever');

            // continue with the pipeline
            return requestDelegate(context);
        });
    });
}
```

In this case the middlewares are specified directly as instances of `Func<RequestDelegate, RequestDelegate>`, instead of custom classes.

Answer (score 0):

You need OWIN middlewear here. Because it is the replacement for HttpModules in vNext.

Write below code in Configure method of `Startup.cs` file

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

and Your custom middlewear may look like:

```
public class MyMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _test;

    public MyMiddleware(RequestDelegate test)
    {
        _test = test;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {   
        return _test.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

Comment: how i will do `url rewriting`?